# Como obtener el campos imagen del formulario y guardarlo en un array de datos en laravel 7

Tags: laravel

Tengo un problema a la hora de guardar los datos en un array en laravel, es decir:

En mi formulario manejo varios datos, entre ellos, varios campos que son para las imágenes, sin embargo, cuando intento guardalas, estas no aparecen ahí, adjunto lo que me arroja el método `dd()`.

```
array:3 [▼
  "question" => array:2 [▼
    "description" => null
    "iframe" => null
  ]
  "answers" => array:4 [▼
    0 => array:3 [▼
      "description" => null
      "iframe" => null
      "is_correct" => "1"
    ]
    1 => array:3 [▼
      "description" => null
      "iframe" => null
      "is_correct" => "1"
    ]
    2 => array:3 [▼
      "description" => null
      "iframe" => null
      "is_correct" => "0"
    ]
    3 => array:3 [▼
      "description" => null
      "iframe" => null
      "is_correct" => "0"
    ]
  ]
]
```

Agrego un extracto de mi formulario (el original es muy extenso y repetitivo). En el, tengo un campo el cual en el `dd()` no se refleja en los arrays, y es el `question[image]` y `answers[n][iframe]`, mi pregunta es ¿Hay alguna manera especial de poder agregar la imagen en el arreglo? o porque esta fallando a la hora de agregar las imágenes al array?

```
<form action="{{ route('questions.store', $questionnaires->id) }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <h2>Pregunta</h2>
  <textarea name="question[description]"></textarea>
  <textarea name="question[iframe]"></textarea>
  <input name="question[image]" type="file" accept="image/*">

  <h2>Respuestas N</h2>
  <textarea name="answers[0][description]"></textarea>
  <textarea name="answers[0][iframe]"></textarea>
  <input name="answers[0][image]" type="file" accept="image/*">
</form>
```

**Edit 1**

Como estoy haciendo pruebas, en el método store lo hago así:

```
public function store(){
  dd($request->all());
}
```

**Edit 2**

Agrego los modelos de Question y Answer

Question.php

```
class Question extends Model{
  protected $fillable = [
    'description', 'iframe', 'image',
  ];

  protected $guarded = [];

  public function questionnaire(){
    return $this->belongsTo(Questionnaire::class);
  }

  public function answers(){
    return $this->hasMany(Answer::class);
  }

  public function responses(){
    return $this->hasMany(SurveyResponse::class);
  }
}
```

Answer.php

```
class Answer extends Model{
  protected $fillable = [
      'question_id', 'description', 'iframe', 'image', 'is_correct', 'select'
    ];

    public function question(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Question::class);
    }

    public function responses(){
        return $this->hasMany(SurveyResponse::class);
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿Cómo obtienes “los arreglos”? Muestra el código

Comment: Cómo estoy haciendo pruebas para verificar datos, solo hago un simple `dd($request->all()` para ver qué se envía.

Comment: Puedes mostrar tu modelo?

Comment: Listo, he agregado los modelos.